# Angular Material - $mdSideNav - backdrop clickable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having issues with Angular material's $mdSideNav where the content in the backgound is clickable. If there is a button for example on the content behind the md-sidenav it can be clicked through the md-sidenav when open. This I assume may be because the $mdSideNav slides in and does not push.

Can anbody shed any light on this issue?
Any help on this would be greatly received.

Thanks
Ger

Answer (score 0):

From the [directive documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSidenav), you can disable the backdrop. Did you do that ?

**EDIT** Solution found : inspect the background and change the `z-index` CSS property.

Comment: Yes I have. But I do not want to disable the backdrop. If anything having md-disable-backdrop set as false should make the content behind md-side-nav not clickable.

Comment: I believe that you should delete the attribute. As stated in the doc, `**When present in the markup**, the sidenav will not show a backdrop.`

Comment: I haven't got it as an attribute. When I say setting md-disable-backdrop to false It is not assigned and therefore md-sidenav is set to default behavior which is backdrop enabled.

Comment: Sorry then, my bad, misunderstood you. Can't you inspect the background, see the class, and overwrite it with a `z-index` CSS attribute ?

Comment: Yes I can give that a try.

Comment: Hi trichetriche, Thanks alot that worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, I will edit my post, can you mark it as resolved ? BTW, maybe you should open a ticket on Angular Material Github's page, it might be a problem !